# Error: No access, refresh token or API key is set when listing users google calendar events

Tags: node.js, express, google-calendar-api, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm implementing an agent that gets users events from his google calendar account to remind him on his upcoming events using node js.
I went through a guide to how to implement authorization to access users data. But then I'm getting this error when a function is called to list the events.
Here is my config file

```
const port = 3002;
const baseURL = `https://a2727d9a7058.ngrok.io`;
module.exports = {
  // The secret for the encryption of the jsonwebtoken
  JWTsecret: 'mysecret',
  baseURL: 'https://a2727d9a7058.ngrok.io',
  port: port,
  // The credentials and information for OAuth2
  oauth2Credentials: {
    client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    project_id: "xxxxxx", // The name of your project
    auth_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    token_uri: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    redirect_uris: [
      `https://a2727d9a7058.ngrok.io`
    ],
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
    ]
  }
};
```

and this is my main file

```
const express = require('express');
const google = require('googleapis').google;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const dfff = require('dialogflow-fulfillment')

// Google's OAuth2 client
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
// Including our config file
const CONFIG = require('./config');
// Creating our express application
const app = express();


// Allowing ourselves to use cookies
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
// Setting up EJS Views
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname);
console.log(dfff)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // Create an OAuth2 client object from the credentials in our config file
    const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_id, CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_secret, CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.redirect_uris[0]);
    // Obtain the google login link to which we'll send our users to give us access
    const loginLink = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline', // Indicates that we need to be able to access data continously without the user constantly giving us consent
      scope: CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.scopes // Using the access scopes from our config file
    });
    return res.render("index", { loginLink: loginLink });
  });


app.get('/auth_callback', function (req, res) {
    // Create an OAuth2 client object from the credentials in our config file
    const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_id, CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_secret, CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.redirect_uris[0]);
    if (req.query.error) {
      // The user did not give us permission.
      return res.redirect('/error');
    } else {
      oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code, function(err, token) {
        if (err)
          return res.redirect('/');
  
        // Store the credentials given by google into a jsonwebtoken in a cookie called 'jwt'
        res.cookie('jwt', jwt.sign(token, CONFIG.JWTsecret));
        return res.redirect('/');
      });
    }
  });

  app.post('/', express.json(),(req,res)=>{
    //if (!req.cookies.jwt) {
      // We haven't logged in
      //return res.redirect('/');
    //}
    const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_id, CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_secret, CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.redirect_uris[0]);
    const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3' , auth:oauth2Client});
    
    const agent = new dfff.WebhookClient({
        request : req,
        response : res
      })
      function welcome(agent){
        agent.add("Hi, I'm Rem. Please click on remind me button if you want to be reminded on your upcoming events!")
      }
    
      function listEvents(agent){ 
        return calendar.events.list({
        'calendarId': 'primary',
        'auth':oauth2Client,
        'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
        'showDeleted': false,
        'singleEvents': true,
        'maxResults': 1,
        'singleEvents': true,
        'orderBy': 'startTime'
     }).then((err,response)=> {
        let events = response.result.items;
        if (events.length !== 0) {
            var event = events[i];
            var when = event.start.dateTime;
            if (!when) {
              when = event.start.date;
            }
              agent.add('Be ready for '+ event.summary + ' event '+ 'at ' + when )
          }
        else {
              agent.add('You dont have any upcoming events.');
        }
      });   
         
      }
    
      let intenMap = new Map()
      intenMap.set('Default_Welcome_Intent',welcome)
      intenMap.set('Remind_me',listEvents)

      agent.handleRequest(intenMap)
   
  });

  // Listen on the port defined in the config file
app.listen(CONFIG.port, function () {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${CONFIG.port}`);
  });
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you please indicate where in this code you are getting the error?

Comment: When listEvents() function is called I get this error

Comment: I don't think you are going through the process of getting authorized and retrieving an access token. You should set credentials using the token with `oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);`. Look at the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs#step_2_set_up_the_sample) for an example.